# NgBootstrap Typehead, how to get "No Result found" message for invalid string

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ng-bootstrap

Have functionality like, need to get typeahead functionality for the valid data, this is working fine. But could you please suggest me how to get `No Results found` message for invalid string.
And if we didn't select from typeahead(manually entered value should be show blank if we are not selecting from typeahead), can we show it like blank in textbox.
Here is my sample code,

```
 subAccountItemObservable: Observable<any>;
 asyncAccountValue: string;
   this.subAccountItemObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
      observer.next(this.asyncAccountValue);
    }).mergeMap((token: string) =>{
      const test1 = (document.getElementById('idTest') as HTMLInputElement).value;
       return this.http.get('/testAPI/getTestAPIRecords',{params: {param1: param1}});
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <input
      id="idsubAccountItemObservable"
      [(ngModel)]="asyncAccountValue"
      [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
      [typeahead]="subAccountItemObservable"
      (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
      (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
      class="form-control searchInput"
      placeholder="Sub Account"
      required
    />
  </div>
```

Can we get "No Results Found" for invalid string ?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use `resultTemplate` to show your own template

**`component.ts`**

```
constructor(private _service: WikipediaService) {}

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => (this.searching = true)),
      switchMap(term =>
        this._service.search(term).pipe(
          map((x: any) => {
            if (x.length > 0) {
              this.searchFailed = false;
              return x;
            } else {
              this.searchFailed = true;
              return ["No Results Found"];
            }
          })
        )
      ),
      tap(() => (this.searching = false))
    );

  formatter = x => x;

  typeaheadOnSelect(evt: NgbTypeaheadSelectItemEvent) {
    if (evt.item == "No Results Found") {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

**`component.html`**

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
  <ngb-highlight *ngIf="!searchFailed" [result]="r" [term]="t"></ngb-highlight>
  <button class="d-button ngb-highlight" *ngIf="searchFailed" disabled>
    No Record Found
  </button>
</ng-template>

<label for="typeahead-template">Search for a state:</label>
<input
  id="typeahead-template"
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  [(ngModel)]="model"
  [ngbTypeahead]="search"
  [resultTemplate]="rt"
  (selectItem)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
  [inputFormatter]="formatter"
/>
```

here the working **`stackblitz`** demo:

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3wzr3-vxfppg?file=src/app/typeahead-template.html**

### Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is a not really a solution. No one said "No Results Founds" could never be a valid option. And in general working with strings this way is very buggy.. "i8n?!"